# android get news article content

Tags: java, android

I am creating a news app and have the url to the site of the articles e.g http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-33379571 and I need a way to extract the **content** from the article.

I have tried jsoup but that gives all the html tags and there is one `<main-article-body>` but that gives the link to the article which I am trying to extract. I know boilerpipe does it exactly but that doesnt work with android, I am really stuck with this problem.

Any help will be much much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on few data extraction applications in.Net (c#) and have used regular expressions to extract content from news website.

The basic idea is to first extract all a href links (as needed) and then fetching details content by making web request. Finally using regular expressions to extract news body data.

Note: A problem with this process is that you will need to change your regular expressions when data source site changes.